# How to iteration on $scope variable in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have code like this :

```
$scope.maps = [
    new google.maps.LatLng($scope.longitude[0], $scope.latitude[0]),
    new google.maps.LatLng($scope.longitude[1], $scope.latitude[1]),
    new google.maps.LatLng($scope.longitude[2], $scope.latitude[2])];
```

How to simplify in AngularJS style to take more iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$scope.maps = [];
$scope.longitude.forEach(function(el, i) {
  $scope.maps.push(new google.maps.LatLng(el, $scope.latitude[i]));
});

// or

$scope.maps = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.longitude.length; ++i) {
  $scope.maps.push(new google.maps.LatLng($scope.longitude[i], $scope.latitude[i]));
}
```

Comment: Cool, as expectations. Thanks @CodeiSir

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the CodeiSir answer. 
Is not "Angular" iteration what he showed is javascript. You can use it for read data too, as you use the angular ng-repeat in the html.

[more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)